# Need a reference for a trigonometric inequality

Tags: reference-request, real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, inequalities, trigonometric-functions

In my old high school notebook (20 years ago), the following inequality appears with its proof:

$$1+\cos x + \frac{1}{2}\cos 2x + \cdots + \frac{1}{n}\cos nx \geq 0$$
for any real $x$ and positive integer $n$.

I am not the one that created this inequality. So the my question is where references for this inequality can be found.

Comment: You should be able to find a closed form for the derivative.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the last sentence on page 16 of [this paper](https://www.dcce.ibilce.unesp.br/%7Edimitrov/papers/main.pdf), this inequality was proved by

W. H. Young, On certain series of Fourier, Proc. London Math. Soc. (2) 11
(1912), 357–366.

Comment: Which you can buy here: https://londmathsoc.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1112/plms/s2-11.1.357 for the reasonable price of $42.00.

Comment: When you say *reasonable*, you're being sarcastic, right?

Comment: If this is [William Henry Young](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Henry_Young) then the UK copyright may have expired in July 2012.

Comment: Thank you very much, I can read Young's paper in Jstor. They provide  each reader 100 free articles each month.

Comment: @DavidHandelman Of course...

Comment: @VuThanhTung have you heard of scihub?

Comment: Oh, I realize that I read https://www.jstor.org/stable/93235?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents instead. The result in that paper seems more general.

Comment: @EFinat-S , I know what scihub is :)

Answer (score 1):

A long comment: the derivative is not positive for all $x$, $n$. Thus there is the need for some more sophisticated argument than monotonicity.

The derivative is $$ - \Im \left( e^{ix}\cdot \frac{e^{inx} -1}{e^{ix}-1} \right).$$
The derivative being positive corresponds to $$\textrm{arg}\left( e^{ix}\cdot \frac{e^{inx} -1}{e^{ix}-1} \right) \le 0 .$$
Using additivity of arg, this reformulates as $$ \textrm{arg}(e^{ix}) -\textrm{arg}(e^{ix} -1 ) + \textrm{arg}(e^{inx} -1) \pmod{2 \pi} \in [0, \pi] .$$ Note that $y\equiv nx \pmod{2 \pi} $ can be almost anything if $x$ is irrational, thus in particular we would have $$ \textrm{arg}(e^{ix}) -\textrm{arg}(e^{ix} -1 ) + \textrm{arg}(e^{iy} -1) \pmod{2 \pi} \in [0, \pi] .$$ The $y$-term ranges over $[3\pi/4, 5\pi/4]$, thus we should have $$\textrm{arg}(e^{ix}) -\textrm{arg}(e^{ix} -1 ) \in [5/4\pi, 7/4\pi].$$

If $x$ is very small and positive, the expression is close to $3/4 \pi$, thus it is false.

Comment: Good "long comment", but it becomes much more readable if one displays long equations, rather then writing everything inline. I've made some changes, but feel free to make additional changes to improve readability if you want. Also, of less importance, but rather than using \textrm{arg}, you'll get better spacing if you use \operatorname{arg}. I have not made that change.

Comment: Thanks Joe! I was by phone and I meant to write 'just a comment', then it became too long and I didn't take time to readjust the format. Much nicer now!